# Dynamic Component onClick not working

Tags: javascript, dynamic, reactjs, onclick, state

I have a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsvcqngn/) with the below code.

I have a dynamic component setup, which does work. If I do `var Component = Switch` or set `Component` to some other React component, it works. But I want to be able to have it switch when I click on it.

So I set up an `onClick` event. Yet its not firing. I get no log statements or any change. Any ideas why?

```
var Other = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <h2>Test this craziness</h2>;
  }
});

var Switch = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <h2>A different one to switch with</h2>;
  }
});

var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {on: true};
  },
  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('handleclick');
    this.setState({on: ! this.state.on});
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log(this.state);
    var Component = this.state.on ? this.props.component.name : Switch;
    return <Component onClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello component={{name: Other}} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! When `onClick` is put directly on a Component, like you have done, it is **NOT** set as the onClick function. It is instead placed in `this.props.onClick`. You still need to add the `onClick` to your actual DOM Elements. See the attached [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsvcqngn/2/)!

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. So then the other option would be to wrap it in a `div` and attach it there instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `onClick` attribute to an actual HTML element, i.e.

```
var Other = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <h2 onClick={this.props.onClick}>Test this craziness</h2>;
  }
});
```